# sort NSMutableArray created from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

i want to sort an NSMutableArray created from a xml parsing with XMLReader

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.to.xml"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictPos = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:urlData error:&error];  
NSMutableArray *arrayEquipos = [[dictPos objectForKey:@"posiciones"] objectForKey:@"equipo"];
```

this is a piece of xml

```
<posiciones>
<equipo id="5" orden="1" padre="21" key="bocajuniors" nombreCorto="Boca" paisId="1" paisSigla="ARG" nombreasociacion="Boca Jrs.">
    <nombre>Boca Juniors</nombre>
    <prom>1.583</prom>
</equipo>
</posiciones>
```

what i want to sort is arrayEquipos sorted by tag 'prom' descendent.
thanks!

EDIT: in java i do like this:

```
Collections.sort(arrayEquipos, new MySalaryComp());


class MyEquipoComp implements Comparator<DescensoModel> {

@Override
    public int compare(DescensoModel e1, DescensoModel e2) {
        if((Float.parseFloat(e1.getProm())) < Float.parseFloat(e2.getProm())){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

DescensoModel:

```
public class DescensoModel  {

private String equipo;
private String prom;

public String getEquipo() {
    return equipo;
}

public void setEquipo(String equipo) {
    this.equipo = equipo;
}

public void setProm(String prom) {
    this.prom = prom;
}
public String getProm() {
    return prom;
}

}
```

Comment: Cool story bro. You've outlined a problem that you need to solve. It doesn't make much sense to your readers, since the tag "prom" only appears once in your data. You should log a larger sample of your  arrayEquipos array to the console and edit your post to show us that larger sample. Then you should see if you can figure out how to parse the data, and tell us about specific problems you have with your attempts, rather than asking your readers to solve your problem for you.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for NSArray and NSMutableArray???

Comment: Duncan C: If i find myself searching the solution in stackoverflow is because i can not figured out. I do not want to others solve my problems, im just searching for help. Thanks aniway.

Hot Licks: What do i have to look? Im pretty new with objective c.

Answer (score 1):

`[arrayEquipos sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"prom" ascending:YES]]]`

Using `prom.doubleValue` as the key may work as well.

Comment: i tried many different ways, no one works. im getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Comment: That's helpful. Which selector? Which instance? "unrecognised selector sent to instance" is one of the two most asked beginner questions.

Comment: Good-- without changes?  I typed it without using XCode for static analysis warnings, so I'm wondering what the issue was.  If you accept your own answer, yet found this useful, vote this one up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out:

First i created a class called Equipo

```
@interface Equipo : NSObject

@property NSString *nombre;
@property NSString *prom;

@end
```

then i created an nsmutable aux array and i filled it

```
arrayEquiposAux = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[arrayEquipos count]];
for(int i=0;i<[arrayEquipos count];i++){
    Equipo *equipo = [[Equipo alloc] init];
    equipo.nombre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[arrayEquipos objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nombre"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    equipo.prom = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[arrayEquipos objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"prom"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    [arrayEquiposAux addObject: equipo];
}
```

then, YES! i can sorted that array

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayEquiposAux sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Equipo *e1, Equipo *e2){
    return [e1.prom compare:e2.prom];
}];
```

Comment: 2 things - you should make the parsing in the `Equipo` class, e.g. in an `init` method (`initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary`).  This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29481912/669586 is an easier solution for your last step.

Comment: YEESS!! it's better! now it works! thanks! and obviusly thanks to stevesliva!